# Build Assembler Block using seize delay release

Tags: anylogic

How do I build Assembler block using smaller elements.

For example: Service block consists of seize + delay +  release.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not super easy, but it's one of the exercises of my course that you can find at [noorjax.teachable.com](https://noorjax.teachable.com)

you can use wait blocks to wait for the quantity of parts to be accumulated, then combine and batch blocks to combine everything together into a service block.

[image: assembler]

Comment: Thank you Felipe, a follow-up question: How can we release the wait block items according to bah size, I tried to think the java code but couldn't get working solution.

Comment: if(wait.size()==batch.capacity && wait1.size()==batch1.capacity && wait2.size()==batch2.capacity) {wait.freeAll(); wait1.freeAll(); wait2.freeAll()}

Comment: something like that